# Scheduled Reminders - Limit or Add Recipients

Tags: scheduled-reminders

I am using CiviCRM 4.7.22 on WordPress.

I am having some confusion with setting up Scheduled Reminders for Memberships.  Ideally, I would like the member to receive an automatic email notice that their membership account is about to expire 30 days before the End Date.

The "Limit or Add Recipients" field is what is causing me confusion.  There are three options: "Neither", "Limit to", and "Also Include".  How does this need to be set to ensure that only the member whose account is about to expire is automatically sent an email notice?

I am thinking just leaving it at "neither" is all I need to do, but I am not sure and the documentation is not helping to ease my confusion.  I am hoping someone can help clear this up for me.

Thank you.

Comment: I tried setting to "Neither" as peterb suggested. I am still not getting any scheduled reminders. Maybe I am doing the test wrong. I created a test membership account and gave it 1 days before it expires. Then In scheduled reminders I set it to begin sending reminders 50 hours before the account end date and to repeat every 1 hour until 1 hour before the end date. I also set the Scheduled Job to "Always". I still haven't received anything. Here are my screen shots. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong there. Thank you, [![Scheduled Reminder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1A8Bl.jpg)](ht

Comment: Thank you everyone By following your advice, I now confirmed that the scheduled reminders are working properly. Now I need to open another question about the Renewal link.

Answer (score 1):

The field basically means, having selected who should get the reminder based on the Entity settings, do you then want to further restrict who gets it, and/or do you want to include folk who don't meet the Entity criteria to also get it.

If you just want the folk who should get it, to get it, then use Neither

Comment: I just need to make sure the members who meet that criteria get it. It is at neither now, and I haven't been getting it, but I suspect I am doing the test wrong.  Can you advise on a test you would run and I will try that

Answer (score 0):

The help screen on the "Limit to" and "also include" options is confusing.  But I have it set to "Neither" and it works just fine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that and I am still not receiving any scheduled reminders.   Maybe I am doing the test wrong.